# Calculate 'NEW COLUMN' from column 'A' based on condition from column 'B"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF roughly with columns: date, amount, currency.

There are several CURRENCY types.

I need to create a new column (USD) which will be a calculation of 
( AMOUNT*EXCHANGE RATE ) based on CURRENCY type.

There are multiple EXCHANGE RATES to be applied.

I cant figure out the code/approach to do so.

Maybe df.where() should help but i keep getting errors.

Thank you

```py
df['RUR'] = df.where(df['CUR']=='KES', df['AMOUNT']*3, axis=1)
or
df['RUR'] = df['AMOUNT'].apply(lambda x: x*2 if df['CUR']=='KES' else None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
df['RUR'] = np.where(df['CUR']=='KES',df['AMOUNT']*3,np.nan)
```

## second sol

you can use.loc and apply condition in it.

```
df.loc[df['CUR']=='KES','RUR']=df['AMOUNT']*3
```